# Cookies added in an OpenIdConnect middleware EventHandler do not persist when not on localhost

Tags: cookies, .net-core

So I am using OpenId Connect and the `AddOpenIdConnect` configuration method to setup Authentication with Auth0.  I have fully tested it locally using `localhost` as the domain of my cookies and everything works great!  However, as soon as I release this to a production environment the cookies no longer seem to persist. The crazy thing is I am logging the `context.Response.Headers` directly after the `context.Response.Cookies.Append(...)` method and locally they are printed as expected, but in production they do not.

```cs
OnTokenValidated = (context) =>
{
    var accessToken = context.TokenEndpointResponse.AccessToken;

    var domain = HostingEnvironment.IsProduction() ? $"{cookieOptions.Domain}.{cookieOptions.Extension}" : "localhost";

    context.Response.Cookies.Append("access_token", accessToken, new CookieOptions
    {
        Domain = domain,
        SameSite = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.SameSiteMode.Lax,
        Expires = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddHours(10),
        HttpOnly = true,
        Secure = HostingEnvironment.IsProduction(),
        Path = "/"
    });

    var idToken = context.TokenEndpointResponse.IdToken;

    context.Response.Cookies.Append("id_token", idToken, new CookieOptions
    {
        Domain = domain,
        SameSite = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.SameSiteMode.Lax,
        Expires = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddHours(10),
        HttpOnly = false,
        Secure = HostingEnvironment.IsProduction(),
        Path = "/"
    });

    // Right here is where I can see the difference. Even though I am printing out the headers directly after appending them, they never are set in production.
    context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<ILogger<Startup>>().LogWarning($"[HEADERS] {JsonConvert.SerializeObject(context.Response.Headers)}");

    return Task.CompletedTask;
},
```

I even went as far as looked at the implementation of `IResponseCookies.Append(...)` to see what could be going on but its very simple and I don't see any way it could be failing to add these to the Headers.

https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/bc7092a32b1943c7f17439e419d3f66cd94ce9bd/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http/Internal/ResponseCookies.cs#L50

```cs
public void Append(string key, string value, CookieOptions options)
{
    if (options == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(options));
    }

    var setCookieHeaderValue = new SetCookieHeaderValue(
        Uri.EscapeDataString(key),
        Uri.EscapeDataString(value))
    {
        Domain = options.Domain,
        Path = options.Path,
        Expires = options.Expires,
        MaxAge = options.MaxAge,
        Secure = options.Secure,
        SameSite = (Net.Http.Headers.SameSiteMode)options.SameSite,
        HttpOnly = options.HttpOnly
    };

    var cookieValue = setCookieHeaderValue.ToString();

    Headers[HeaderNames.SetCookie] = StringValues.Concat(Headers[HeaderNames.SetCookie], cookieValue);
}
```

Comment: So I ended up taking the implementation of `Append` above and using it directly in my code and now everything works just fine. I have absolutely no idea how this method doesn't work, but mine does. The only possibility I can think of is the `Headers` object being referenced here at the bottom of the method (which is injected in the ctor) is somehow a different object than `context.Response.Headers` in the application code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I finally figured it all out.  The [Auth0 Quickstart for ASP .NET Core 3.x](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/webapp/aspnet-core-3) contains the following lines of code:

```
services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
{
    // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
    options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
    options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
});
```

This enforces "consent" to be required for all Cookies. I have yet to figure out what this means exactly as the MS docs seem to be very limited. After changing this to `false` it all started working again. `false` is the default, it was just the Auth0 Quickstart that added it for some reason.

What further lead to my confusion was I tried to look at the implementation of `Cookies.Append(...)` and I found the [ResponseCookies](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/07d115400e4f8c7a66ba239f230805f03a14ee3d/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http/Internal/ResponseCookies.cs) class that implements `IResponseCookies` and ended up copy/pasting that implementation into my code to get it to work.  After digging, I realized its not this implementation but instead [this one](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/beaa2b443d46ef8adaf5c2a89eb475e1893037c2/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.CookiePolicy/ResponseCookiesWrapper.cs) for `ResponseCookiesWrapper` that is actually being used. As you can sees this implementation uses all the extra "consent" logic to make sure you are allowed to add a cookie which apparently I wasn't.

UPDATE:
Sorry what I mentioned was that I had this working only on localhost, but you might ask why it wasn't failing on localhost and PROD. That is because even though the Quickstart shows it hardcoded to `true`, the actual [example code on GitHub](https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-aspnetcore-mvc-samples/blob/master/Quickstart/01-Login/Startup.cs) uses `HostingEnvironment.IsProduction()` which is what I had as well.